# Does the iPad Air support Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: ipad

I'd like to use my Seagate Wireless hard drive with my iPad or even my iPhone 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst the **device hardware does support Wi-Fi Direct**, the limitation in this case is software.

There is currently no software on iOS that connects to a wireless hard drive through Wi-Fi Direct, but that hasn't stopped apps being developed to take advantage of this — Seagate has an app that connects to wireless hard drives:

- http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/services-software/apps/seagate-media-app/